# Changing resolution frequency from 0.00Hz to 60Hz

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, xorg, pi-zero-w-2

Hey all I am new to the Raspberry Pi World so I need a little bit of help.

I have my USB touch screen monitor running just fine. Both work with the resolution of (native) 1280x800.

The issue is that it has noticeable "ghosting/lag" when dragging around windows. Upon looking at the Screen Layout Editor I noticed that the Frequency is set to 0.00Hz:

[image]

I am using a [Mimo monitor](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0026/7132/files/UM-1080_UM-1080C-G_Display_Sell_Sheet_77797.4_-_2018-0905.pdf?946909358858586797) and followed the steps on their [website](https://www.mimomonitors.com/pages/using-our-usb-displays-with-the-raspberry-pi-3) and also watched this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SbVumPBpNQ) video to get myself familiar with what all was needing to be done.

I'm running the latest Raspbian OS (32-bit) on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W.

```
xrandr
===================
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
        Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 800, current 1280 x 800, maximum 1280 x 800
        default connected 1280x800+0+0 0mm x 0mm
        1280x800       0.00*

cat /etc/os-release
===================
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian

hostnamectl
===================
Static hostname: raspberrypi
Icon name: computer
Machine ID: xx
Boot ID: xx
Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Kernel: Linux 5.15.84-v7+
Architecture: arm

sudo inxi -Fxz
===================
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.84-v7+ armv7l bits: 32 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
  Desktop: Openbox 3.6.1 Distro: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
Machine:
  Type: ARM Device System: Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W Rev 1.0 details: BCM2835 
CPU:
  Info: Quad Core model: ARMv7 v7l variant: cortex-a53 bits: 32 type: MCP 
  arch: v7l rev: 4 
  features: Use -f option to see features bogomips: 0 
  Speed: 600 MHz min/max: 600/1000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 600 2: 600 
  3: 600 4: 600 
Graphics:
  Device-1: bcm2835-hdmi driver: vc4_hdmi v: N/A bus ID: N/A 
  Device-2: bcm2835-vc4 driver: vc4_drm v: N/A bus ID: N/A 
  Device-3: DisplayLink MIMO VUE HD type: USB driver: udl bus ID: 1-1.1.1:5 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: fbdev resolution: 1280x800 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1 128 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.3.5 
  direct render: Yes
Info:
  Processes: 174 Uptime: 25m Memory: 490.9 MiB used: 256.7 MiB (52.3%) 
  gpu: 64 MiB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.1 
  Packages: 1376 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.4 inxi: 3.3.01
```

My xorg.conf file looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "FBDEV 0"
Driver "fbdev"
Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "FBDEV 1"
Driver "fbdev"
Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "HDMI"
Device "FBDEV 0"
Monitor "Monitor name 0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "UGA"
Device "FBDEV 1"
Monitor "Monitor name 1"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "Default Layout"
Screen 0 "HDMI"
Screen 1 "UGA" LeftOf "HDMI"
EndSection
```

I'm not all that formular with the commands in the terminal nor the types of things I can add to the xorg.conf file for changing this so that's why I am reaching out to see if I can get some help to solve the frequency issue.

Thanks!

**update 1**

For reference when its connected to a windows 11 PC:

[image]

Comment: why is the frequency setting an issue?

Comment: @jsotola I figured it was needed i order to not have it lag when i move windows around.

Comment: 0 Hz would mean that the video would never change ...anyway, your screen is not connected to a video card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough reinstalling the Raspbian and installing all the drivers seemed to bring it up to the 60Hz magically...

[image]